# Who are the 'Tiursk tribe' of Central Asia?

Tags: russia, language, steppe-nomads, central-asia

I am reading this passage in a book called [Overland to China](https://books.google.com/books?id=4fdVAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA364&dq=overland%20to%20china&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj-hKL9zIjwAhULv54KHbVLAw8Q6AEwAXoECAIQAg#v=onepage&q=tiursk%20&f=false) (1900) which on page 66 makes mention of a Tiursk tribe in Central Asia.

[image: Overland to China (1900)]

Online searches didn't provide much details except referencing/associating other groups to the Tiursk.

Language of the Jakuts belongs to the Tiursk nationalities. (see *[OnlineLibrary.Wiley.com](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/ajpa.1330210123)*)

My guess is that it's a Russian word form for Turk/Turkic. But I want to be sure because the google translation is not the same.

Comment: if its the book by  [Archibald Ross Colquhoun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A._R._Colquhoun), he appears to have been a South African living more than a century ago, so its quite possible he just didn't spell "Turkish" the way modern Americans and Englishmen do.

Comment: @T.E.D. also Tiursk, as mentioned in an answer below, is most likely a spelling derived from the Russian pronunciation of 'Turkish' (Тюркские → Tiurkskiy )

Comment: This is most likely 'Turkish tribe(s)' but derived from the Russian pronunciation

Comment: @DmitryKoroliov - I'm pretty sure from context its not talking about one tribe.

Answer (score 11):

Your link to the [Jakut article](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/ajpa.1330210123) holds what I would consider fairly strong evidence. The article (all emphasis mine) specifies that by

> *features, as well as **by their language**, the Jakuts belong to the Tiursk ***nationalities****.

We can look to the wiki article on the [Jakuts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yakuts) and find that

> *The ***Yakut language*** belongs to the Siberian branch of the ***Turkic languages***.*

Another older work, *[The Polar World: a Popular Description of Man and Nature in the Arctic and Antarctic Regions of the Globe](https://books.google.com/books?id=CVZFAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA228&dq=jakut%20language%20constantinople&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwil2vq0norwAhWIDjQIHfMPDZYQ6AEwAXoECAMQAg#v=onepage&q=jakut%20language%20constantinople&f=false)*
By Georg Hartwig, published in 1859, has a chapter on the Jakuts. This also mentions this language connection to the Turkic people:

> Though of a Mongolian physiognomy their language which is said to be
> intelligible at Constantinople distinctly ***points to a Turk extraction***
> and their traditions speak of their original seats as situated on the
> Baikal and Angora whence retreating before more powerful hordes they
> advanced to the Lena where in their turn they dispossessed the weaker
> tribes which they found in possession of the country.

Considering the language connection, and the use of the term *nationalities* indicating something more widespread than a single tribe, I would conclude the term was indicating a Turkic peoples.

Answer (score 10):

The [Russian Wikipedia article for Turkic languages](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B8) is titled Тюркские языки (t-iu-r-k-s-k-i-ie ...), which imho makes it very likely that Tiursk should be read as Turk or Turkic. If you can accept that с and к being out of sequence (or one к missing) is just a clerical error.

The [center of the first Turkic state](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Turkic_Khaganate) was east of the Khangai mountains, which is something like 500 kilometers south of the Sayan mountains and lake Baikal. Don't get fooled by the large djstance between lake Baikal and the modern state of Turkey!

Comment: Or just elision of one of the к's.

Comment: Yes, that is also possible

Answer (score 1):

"Irghana-Kon" mentioned in the cited [Overland to China](https://books.google.com/books?id=4fdVAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA364&dq=overland%20to%20china&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj-hKL9zIjwAhULv54KHbVLAw8Q6AEwAXoECAIQAg#v=onepage&q=tiursk%20&f=false) is actually [the mythical Ergenekon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergenekon). And so "Tiursk tribe" should probably refer to [Turkic peoples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkic_peoples).

Comment: Why do you assert that Irghana-Kon is Ergenekon?  On what basis?

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace per the linked Wikipedia page, mythical Ergenekon was a valley ringed on all sides by high mountains, and it was the cradle of the Turkic peoples.

Comment: I have also read previously about Ergenekon, but what I read is that the myth is also shared by Mongols and Chinese. Not much credible information appears to be available on this myth/idea.

Comment: @Samid This book doesn't appear as credible source either. The author simpy tells some variation of that myth.